# What does the idiom "for good" come from?

Tags: etymology

I'd like to know why this means forever.
As a foreign English speaker, when I heard this idiom I thought it meant like for something good. 
What was the origin of "for good" ?

Answer (score -1):

I heard someone say it derives from "for good many years".

Comment: You may have heard somebody say that, but "for good many years" is not English. "For _a_ good many years" is a common English phrase, with approximately the right meaning; but it is hard to see how "for good" could come from it.